# R: apply function to two consecutive dataframes in a list of dfs

Tags: r, dataframe

so I know that you can apply a function to a list of dfs, but I cannot work this here out:

I have a list of n dataframes, let's say from df1 to df4 (numbered accordingly).

```
df1 <- data.frame(name= c("mark", "peter", "lily"), column1= c(1,2,3),column2= c(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(name= c("mark", "liam", "peter"), column1= c(7,8,9),column2= c(1,2,3))
df3 <- data.frame(name= c("felix", "liam", "peter"), column1= c(3,5,8),column2= c(1,5,8))
df4 <- data.frame(name= c("felix", "lily", "liam"), column1= c(6,2,6),column2= c(4,2,2))
```

Now I story my dsf in a list:

```
df_list = mget(ls(pattern = "df[1-4]"))
```

Then, I have this functions

```
df_combined <- dfx %>%
  left_join(dfy, by="name") %>%
  mutate(combined=(column1.x + column2.x)/column2.y)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(combined)) %>%
  select(name,combined)

add_match_column<-function(df){
  df %>% left_join(df_combined)
}

df_list_matched <- df_list %>%
  map(add_match_column)
```

Now is there a way to apply this function to consecutive dfs?
I.e. in the first "iteration" is dfx = df1, dfy = df2 and in the following "iteration" dfx = df2, dfy = df3 and so on...

Please keep in mind that I have way more dfs in reality, numbered by years.

Edits:

1. If dfx is the last df of the list, then the code should stop there not making any further iterations
2. The output should be that the result of the df_combined function is a new column in every dfy. Thus, the first df in my list is left out.

Comment: what is dfy when dfx is the last element in the list?

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use `dplyr` for your tasks or could you also use simple base R?

Comment: What is your expected output in your example?

Comment: @JKupzig dplyr is not mandatory, for me as a beginner its just a bit easier to understand I think, but be happy for R based approaches :)

Comment: @Maël
I have made the respective edits to my questions.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, "ticker" is not defined.

Comment: @JKupzig sry, have changed that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using lapply for iteration:

```
df_list_match <- function(df1, df2){
  new <- merge(df1, df2, by="name", all.y=T)
  new$combined <- (new$column1.x + new$column2.x)/(new$column2.y)
  new <- new[!is.na(new$combined), c(1,4,5,6)]
  names(new) <- c("name", "column1", "column2", "combined")
  return(new)
}

result <- lapply(2:length(df_list), function(x) {df_list_match(df_list[[x-1]],df_list[[x]]) })

result
[[1]]
   name column1 column2 combined
1  mark       7       1 5.000000
2 peter       9       3 2.333333

[[2]]
   name column1 column2 combined
1  liam       5       5      2.0
2 peter       8       8      1.5

[[3]]
   name column1 column2 combined
1 felix       6       4        1
2  liam       6       2        5
```

If you want to have all original entries from the data.frame (display NA if an entry in dfy is not in dfx) you can just delete `!is.na(new$combined)` in the function.

Comment: you are the man. Works perfectly, thanks :)